# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS cpu high usages?

Tags: cpu, fan

I recently upgrade my Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 LTS. For some reason it started using a lot of my CPU, also the fan became extremely loud too. I try to located it by typing top in the terminal then killing the issue, unfortunately no luck. Any ideas?

My laptop is Toshiba Satellite L745-S4210, I upgraded the RAM to 8 GB, also I added an SSD to it. FYI

I also posted this on Reddit for addition help :)

https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/8q7qym/ubuntu_1804_lts_cpu_high_usages/

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Try running powertop to see which is the offending app.

```
sudo apt-get install powertop
sudo powertop
```

You can find more information about it in [powertop github](https://github.com/fenrus75/powertop)